# Extract previous row calculated value for use in current row calculations - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Have a requirement where I would need to rope the calculated value of the previous row for calculation in the current row.

The following is a sample of how the data currently looks :-

| ID | Date | Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-15 | 30 |
| 2 | 2022-02-18 | 30 |
| 3 | 2022-03-15 | 90 |
| 4 | 2022-05-15 | 30 |

The following is the output What I am expecting :-

| ID | Date | Days | CalVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-15 | 30 | 2022-02-14 |
| 2 | 2022-02-18 | 30 | 2022-03-16 |
| 3 | 2022-03-15 | 90 | 2022-06-14 |
| 4 | 2022-05-15 | 30 | 2022-07-14 |

The value of CalVal for the first row is Date + Days
From the second row onwards it should take the CalVal value of the previous row and add it with the current row Days

Essentially, what I am looking for is means to access the previous rows calculated value for use in the current row.

Is there anyway we can achieve the above via Postgres SQL? I have been tinkering with window functions and even recursive CTEs but have had no luck :(

Would appreciate any direction!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your example, because now this dates look quite random. 2022-03-16 is not 2022-02-18 + 30 days

Comment: Could you provide a little context - are you trying to get a query result, or do you really want to "fix" the wrong dates in the table (which appear to be out of synch and therefore of little use)? I.e., looking for a select here, or really after an update instead? Also, is this a one time thing or something you would have to do frequently ... and finally, are we talking about a few hundred rows of data or potentially hundreds of thousands of rows or more? As I see this problem, only the first date really matters - the rest can all be "calculated". Would rather use python not sql though :).

Comment: @Kadet - 2022-03-16 is 2022-02-14 + 30 (basically CalVal of the 1st row). So for the second row CalVal value its taking CalVal from the previous row and adding it to the Days from the current row. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @topsail - I am trying to get a query result. My essential need is however to somehow refer the calculated value of the previous row for calculation within the existing row. This is more or less for my learning and understanding. Recursive CTE is a possible. However, was wondering whether there are any other approaches to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    id,
    date,
    coalesce(
        days - (lag(days, 1) over (order by date, days))
        , days) as days,
     first_date + cast(days as integer) as newdate
from
    (
        select 
            -- get a running sum of days
            id,
            first_date,
            date,
            sum(days) over (order by date, days) as days
        from
        (
            select 
                -- get the first date
                id,
                (select min(date) from table1) as first_date, 
                date,
                days
            from 
                table1
        ) A
    ) B
```

This query get the exact output you described. I'm not at all ready to say it is the best solution but the strategy employed is to essential create a running total of the "days" ... this means that we can just add this running total to the first date and that will always be the next date in the desired sequence. One finesse: to put the "days" back into the result, we calculated the current running total less the previous running total to arrive at the original amount.

Comment: Thanks for this! However, independent of whatever calculation in CalVal. Is there a way to generically get the calculated value of the previous row for use in the current row? Window functions would work over already 'defined' columns but not what is being generated on the fly it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that table name is `table1`

```sql
select 
  id, 
  date, 
  days, 
  first_value(date) over (order by id) + 
   (sum(days) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row))
   *interval '1 day' calval
 from table1;
```

We just add cumulative sum of days to first date in table. It's not really what you want to do (we don't need date from previous row, just cumulative days sum)

**Solution with recursion**

```sql
with recursive prev_row as (
    select id, date, days, date+ days*interval '1 day' calval
    from table1
    where id = 1
union all
    select t.id, t.date, t.days, p.calval + t.days*interval '1 day' calval
    from prev_row p
    join table1 t on t.id = p.id+ 1
)
select *
from prev_row
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However, independent of whatever calculation in CalVal. Is there a way to generically get the calculated value of the previous row for use in the current row? Window functions would work over already 'defined' columns but not what is being generated on the fly it would seem.

Comment: @user9429934 I've added example with recursive query